# Python - how to? Filtering out multiple bands of frequencies either in Frequency(FFT) or Time(filtfilt)

Tags: python-3.x, signal-processing, fft

I have a time series signal which I want to filter out anything that isn't a multiple of my base frequency.

I figured a digital comb filter would be a good place to start but it isn't giving me a 1.0 coefficient at all of my base frequencies and I'm not sure why.

[image: iircomb filter frequency responses]

```
from scipy import signal
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

MySignal = [some time series data....]
BaseFreq = 90.0
fs = 36000
F0 = BaseFreq
F1 = BaseFreq * 2
Q0 = 50.0

# Basic Notch Filter for filtering out even harmonics
b,a = signal.iircomb(F0*2, Q0, ftype='notch', fs=fs)
freq, h = signal.freqz(b,a, fs=fs)
response = abs(h)

# Basic Peak Filter for
d,c = signal.iircomb(F0, Q0, ftype='peak', fs=fs)
freq2 ,h2 = signal.freqz(d,c, fs=fs)
response2 = abs(h2)

# Plots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(12,6),sharex=True)
ax[0].plot(freq, response)
ax[1].plot(freq2, response2)
plt.show()
```

Another way I have attempted to do this is in the frequency domain using FFT and high, low and bandpass is all easy to do, but I can't seem to find a nice comb to properly claw out the non-base frequencies.

The other idea I had was to apply a Kaiser window around my base frequencies, but I'm not sure how or that I can even use that in the frequency domain..

Appreciate and ideas even if it's just a link to go do a pile of reading!

Comment: If you only care about _exact_ multiples of your frequency, the only additional information you're going to get out of an FFT is phase and amplitude. Are those what you're really looking for?

Comment: Can you link a data dump of your time signal?

Comment: When you say "filter out anything that isn't a multiple of my base frequency", is your desired output a sine at that frequency, or similar-looking peaks to what's already in your time series? If the latter, then a strict bandpass filter is not really what you want.

Comment: @Reinderien I'm only interested in the base + odd harmonics of the base frequency. The FFT it giving me amplitude info which is showing me that there is a small amount of energy outside of my base+odd harmonics bins that is distorting the original signal. Unfortunately can't provide the signal. I'm just looking to remove some of this noise not related to the base frequency and have a slightly cleaner signal that looks very similar.

Answer (score 4):

Your filter does have 1.0 gain peaks, but the plot resolution is too low to see it. By default, [scipy.signal.freqz](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqz.html) samples the frequency response at 512 points. This often isn't enough, especially to resolve narrow notches or peaks in the response. Try increasing to 10K points, like `signal.freqz(b,a, worN=10000, fs=fs)`.

There is another problem: while the first filter is notching the even harmonics as desired, the peaks filter is shifted by half a multiple off the intended response. The fix is to use the "`pass_zero = True`" option. As explained in [the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.iircomb.html),

> **pass_zero : bool, optional**
> If False (default), the notches (nulls) of the filter are centered on frequencies `[0, w0, 2*w0, ...]`, and the peaks are centered on the midpoints `[w0/2, 3*w0/2, 5*w0/2, ...]`. If True, the peaks are centered on `[0, w0, 2*w0, ...]` (passing zero frequency) and vice versa.

(Side note: the `pass_zero` option is relatively new, added in version 1.9.0. If your installation lacks it, you can simply flip the sign on the last coefficients of `b` and `a`.)

Here is what I get with these changes. I've zoomed in on the first few multiples.

[image]

**Code:**

```py
# Copyright 2023 Google LLC.
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

BaseFreq = 90.0
fs = 36000
F0 = BaseFreq
Q0 = 50.0

# Notch filter for removing the even harmonics.
b,a = signal.iircomb(F0*2, Q0, ftype='notch', fs=fs)
freq, h = signal.freqz(b,a, worN=10000, fs=fs)
response = abs(h)

# Peak filter for passing only multiples of F0.
d,c = signal.iircomb(F0, Q0, ftype='peak', fs=fs)
d[-1] *= -1  # Implement `pass_zero=True` pre-1.9.0.
c[-1] *= -1
freq2, h2 = signal.freqz(d,c, worN=10000, fs=fs)
response2 = abs(h2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(12,6),sharex=True)
ax[0].plot(freq, response)
ax[0].set_xlim(0, 280)
ax[0].set_ylabel('Gain')
ax[1].plot(freq2, response2)
ax[1].set_xlim(0, 280)
ax[1].set_xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ax[1].set_ylabel('Gain')
plt.show()
```

Comment: A beautiful reply. Thank you Pascal for a very detailed and informative response. I really appreciate it!